# How to access libraries inside a controller?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I'm building a small framework that I can use for repeated mundane stuff on future small projects.

I'm stuck on the best way to access libraries from inside a controller. I originally implemented a system similar to CodeIgniter's whereby my main controller class is basically a super object and loads all the classes into class variables which are then accessed by extending the controller and doing like `$this->class->method()`

I find that a little ugly, though. So I thought of just loading each class individually on a per-use basis in each controller method.

What's the best (cleanest) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only ever have one instance of each class, you could create a simple service container.

```
class ServiceContainer
{
    protected $services;

    public function get($className)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($className, $this->services)) {
            $this->services[$className] = new $className;
        }

        return $this->services[$className]
    }
}
```

Then create one ServiceContainer instance per application.  Inject the container into all of your controllers and use

```
public function someAction()
{
    $this->container->get('Mailer')->send($email_data);
}
```

Simple example, and obviously needs a lot of work to make useable (for instance autoloading needed and handling of file paths for ease of use, or easier way to add services without getting them, etc).

Comment: This is sort of what I ended up going with. But the syntax seems too length so I just went with a procedural function with a static array.

Answer (score 2):

I dont like the way CodeIgniter does it. Its never seemed right to me. I favor an auto loading class pushed onto the spl_autoload stack. And then just calling the class as normal like:

`$class = new SomeClass();`

Comment: But what if I need to use the class somewhere else at the same time and don't want to instantiate it twice? Should I just make all my libraries singletons? Or should I make a function to load classes that assigns a static array to the object and then just return the object if it was already loaded (CodeIgniter's approach)?

Comment: @CrazeD There's nothing wrong in implementing singletons if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides autoload functionality with [SPL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) and [spl_autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) (and related functions). You can register a custom autoloader for your library code.

For the shared functionality handled by your application, have you considered the [Front Controller design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern)?